# Force SSL for three of six sites sharing a Drupal 8 codebase

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-8

In my /sites folder, I have six folders representing six different TLDs.  Only three of these TLDs (tld1.com, tld2.com, tld3.com) have SSL certs.  All six share a single .htaccess file in root.  I know how to force SSL for a single TLD in .htaccess, but not for three TLDs.  (FYI, I have **rewrite base /** uncommented in .htaccess.)  I'd appreciate any advice / guidance.  Thanks.

Comment: What directive are you currently using to redirect HTTP to HTTPS?

Comment: At the moment I am using no redirect directives in htaccess... the latter is the standard file that is bundled with Drupal 8.  Would it help if I posted it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only three of these TLDs (tld1.com, tld2.com, tld3.com) have SSL certs.

Those aren't "[TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain)s" - those are simply *domains* - they all share the same TLD!

> I know how to force SSL for a single TLD in .htaccess, but not for three TLDs

The process is very much the same. In fact, you may need to modify your existing directive if it is specific to your server. (Different servers can require slightly different methods to redirect HTTP to HTTPS, depending on how it's configured. The method I've used below, using the `HTTPS` server variable would be the most common.)

You just need to add some conditions (`RewriteCond` directives) to your existing HTTP to HTTPS redirect that checks the hostname being requested.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example1\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example2\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example3\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Note the absence of the `OR` flag on the last `RewriteCond` directive.

You can also combine these conditions since you only have 3 domains you need to check for, and they all appear to share the same TLD (ie. `.com`).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(example1|example2|example3)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

> **UPDATE:** I forgot to mention that I do not / not want "www" to be part of the URL. Can the code you shared above be tweaked to accomplish same?

You could implement this as two separate redirects *before* the above HTTP to HTTPS redirect. One for the domains you want to redirect to HTTPS and another for the rest (that should stay on HTTP).

Incidentally, all these redirects should be placed *before* any existing Drupal directives you may have.

For example:

```
# Remove www subdomain from "secure" domains
# Also redirects to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example1\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example2\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example3\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Remove www subdomain from other (non-secure) domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# HTTP to HTTPS redirect for "secure" (non-www) domains
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST} ^example1\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST} ^example2\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST} ^example3\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The `%1` backreference in the first two rules matches the domain less the www subdomain.

The above could be reduced into something like the following instead if you wish:

```
# HTTP to HTTPS and remove www subdomain for secure domains
# Currently assumes all secure domains share the same TLD (ie. ".com")
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example1|example2|example3)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Remove www subdomain from other (non-secure) domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I forgot to mention that I do not / not want "www" to be part of the URL.  Can the code you shared above be tweaked to accomplish same?

Comment: I've updated my answer to remove the www subdomain as well.

Comment: @MrWhiteThank you!  Works great.  One last question if I may: If I type into the URL "h t t p://www.example.com" it is converted to an SSL'd "example.com.".  So far so good.  However, if I type into the URL "h t t p://example.com) then that is converted into a non-SSL "example.com".  Is there a way to transform the latter as well so that it too converts into a secure site?

Comment: Which rule block are you using? The above rules should already be doing that, providing `example.com` is one of the domains listed as "secure", ie. either `example1.com`, `example2.com` or `example3.com` in the above example? When you say "is converted into a non-SSL "example.com"" - that would seem that nothing is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I am using the first large block of code you provided and everything works.  My previous comment was based on the assumption (faulty I imagine) that people are going to be actually typing `http` into the URL.  I appreciate your time and guidance.

Comment: If someone were to type `http://example.com` (HTTP and non-www) then the 3rd rule would redirect the user to `https://example.com` (HTTPS) - providing `example.com` is one of the "secure" domains listed. Users rarely type the protocol - they will often just type `example.com` (the domain), in which case the browser _defaults_ to `http://` (not-secure). So, yes, a redirect is required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208514/discussion-between-trazom-and-mrwhite).